# re-ordering column names in multiple excel files in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to re-order column names in multiple excel files using the code below. This code is re-arranging column names in only last file. I think it is looping through all the files but may be making/saving changes only in the last file. Any help to make/save changes to all files is much appreciated.

Full Code:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
folder = (r"C:\Users\Documents\Extracted\")


for file_name in Path(folder).glob('*.xlsx'):
    df = pd.read_excel(file_name)
    New_df = df[['Id', 'Title', 'FirstName', 'LastName'']]
 
    New_df.to_csv(file_name.with_suffix('.csv'),index = False)
```

Comment: What's the result of `print(file_name)`, does it contains all your xlsx files?

Comment: Hi, no it contains only last file name